# Binary search tree special case

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

When removing a node with two children in a binary search tree, how many times can the recursive removal of the child node be called?

Comment: Hmmm where is the Java in this question? Dont see any code here.

Comment: Is this a trick question?

Comment: Let's treat it as a trick question

Comment: This has been an extra credit question on two tests in data structures and we have not been given an answer yet. The professor is giving us an answer after the final. He says he had an epiphany and that it is so obvious that once he tells us we will be dumb founded.

Answer (score 1):

Three times: Left child, Right child, Root node.

Comment: But what if the children have children?

Comment: Presumably "two children" means strictly a single root with two child nodes and nothing else. However, if the children have children, then the answer would be something like MAX( ___, ___) with some variables involved... But that's where the "trick" comes in.